# Check excel file contents before import

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using VS2005 C# ASP.NET and SQL Server 2005.

I have a function which import Excel data. I have met a situation when the data inside is inappropriate, it will bring down the SQL Server DB.

E.g. SELECT [Username], [Password] from [userlist$] -> If an excel spreadsheet contains more than [Username] in one column or values below the columns, the server will crash.

E.G. [image]

May I know how can I have a statement to check for this file error before uploading? Prefer `if` `else` statements for checking.

Thank you for any help or examples given.

Below is my code snippet for the excel upload:

```
if (FileImport.HasFile)
    {

        // Get the name of the Excel spreadsheet to upload. 
        string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileImport.FileName);

        // Get the extension of the Excel spreadsheet. 
        string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

        // Validate the file extension. 
        if (strExtension == ".xls" || strExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
                // Generate the file name to save. 
                string strUploadFileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/user01/My Documents/Visual Studio 2005/WebSites/MajorProject/UploadFiles/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;

                // Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
                FileImport.SaveAs(strUploadFileName);

                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

                using (OleDbConnection connection =
                             new OleDbConnection(connStr))
                {
                    string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [COLUMNS]  FROM [userlist$]");

                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);

                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");
                    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
                    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // SQL Server Connection String
                        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>";

                        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                                   new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserDB";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the whole database server is crashing?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, it will give me an error like `the remote host has forcibly closed by the remote host, and the server needs to be restarted in order for me to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of data that is in the Excel spreadsheet, you could read each of the values from the column you are interested in into a Dictionary, for example, and fail the import as soon as you find the first conflict.

For example, using your existing datareeader:

```
Dictionary<string, string> cValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr.Read()) {
      string sValue = dr[0].ToString();
      if (cValue.ContainsKey(sValue)) {
         // There is a duplicate value, so bail
         throw new Exception("Duplicate value " + sValue);
      } else {
         cValues.Add(sValue, sValue);
      }
   }
}

// Now execute the reader on the command again to perform the upload
using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should solve the cause of the problem, which is the database. Apparently, the way you store the data should be via stored procedures which handle wrongly input data.

Also, the constraints on the database tables should prohibit you from storing non-sensical data.